# Passing objects to different threads without using Queue

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm currently trying to write a multithreaded WPF c# application such that UI and other modules run on their respective threads from the start.

However, for example, if I want to pass an object from UI to a module, I want to make sure UI doesn't have to wait for anything and can continue right away. Therefore using Queues don't quiet work in this case as other post had suggested.

Is there any suggestion on I can do this? I'm thinking to use an interface class that connects the two threads or using a volatile variable to hold the object, etc. But none of those doesn't really sound effective. Thanks

Comment: Two threads are independent of each other. They cannot share data unless data is persisted in db. Now, your question is still not clear. What application is it? winform, wpf, ? What are you trying to achieve? What have you tried so far? Some code can be added.

Comment: have you looked into the "lock" keyword? this is designed to make shared variables thread safe. there's not really that much of a concept of "Passing objects to threads" You really want to offload work to a background thread so the UI isn't blocking.

Comment: @Harsh, That is plain wrong, threads can share data easily. That is why C# has lock keyword.

Comment: _"if I want to pass an object from UI to a module, I want to make sure UI doesn't have to wait for anything and can continue right away."_ That is why you **should** use a queue. The queue prevents the UI from waiting.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear for my question and I'm still editing. However, problem I had with queue is that I used lock to prevent conflict between threads. But what might happen is that if dequeue holds the lock, then UI has to wait for it to finish which is not what I want. Thank you for all the responses and I'll try to finish editing soon.

Comment: @MertAkcakaya no, on the contrary, `lock` is used to **prevent** multiple threads from accessing the same data at the same time. You don't need locks to pass data from one thread to another, there are a **lot** of mechanisms - Concurrent collections, IProducerConsumer implementations,  `Progress< T>`, even BlockingCollection. Using the appropriate abstraction, like Tasks or Dataflow makes this even easier

Comment: @JoeHuang *what are you trying to do*? What is the background thread doing? You can use a ConcurrentQueue and avoid locking, although the worker thread will have to poll. Or use `await Task.Run()`. and forget about explicit threading entirely. Or use `ActionBlock< T>` which implements both queueing and concurrent processing. Or use a `BlockingCollection` to pump data from one thread to another

Comment: @JoeHuang _"But what might happen is that if dequeue holds the lock, then UI has to wait for it to finish"_  Why would you produce code that holds the lock. Just |lock the queue|add the data|unlock.  On the other thread. |Lock the queue|dequeue the data|unlock|process the data.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos background thread might be doing time-consuming task. Thanks! I'll look into those.

Comment: @JoeHuang they always do. *What* exactly? Why don't you just write `var result=await Task.Run(thatHeavyMethod(someData));` ? You *don't* need to manage threads yourself in .NET, that's what tasks are for

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen yes, realistically it never take long. However, as part of my task is to prevent delay in case something time-consuming happen between lock/unlock.

Comment: @JoeHuand don't use Queue and locks then, use ConcurrentQueue<T> which is thread-safe. If you *don't* want to preserve state from one execution to another though, you don't need a thread at all. You can process data in the background with `Task.Run`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, You didn't get it. I did not say lock is used to share data, I did say that lock is there because threads can share data.

Comment: @MertAkcakaya perhaps you should read the *documentation* for the `lock` statement. It's only used to prevent threads from accessing the same code path at the same time. It's something to be avoided if possible. That's just one reason why people use ConcurrentQueue<T> or Task.Run

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, You just don't understand, whatever.

Comment: A `lock` **doesn't** lock data. A lock uses the parameter as lock id. So 'locking' the same object, prevents code execution in the lock scope on different threads. You can even create a separate object _(for example SyncRoot)_ which is used to lock execution for manipulating a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't explain what you want to do, so it's hard to give a specific answer. Running some heavy work in the background to avoid blocking the UI describes half of the concurrency problems. The other half has to do with avoiding long waits when a server takes too long to answer.

If you want to perform some long-running job in response to a user's action, eg a click, just use `await` and `Task.Run` :

```
public async void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArguments arg)
{
    ....
    var result=await Task.Run(()=>calculate(someData);
    toolStripLabel1.Text ="Step 1 complete";
    var result2=await Task.Run(()=>someOtherCalculation(result));
    txtBox1.Text=result2;
}
```

This will use a background thread from a threadpool to run the calculations and release the UI thread. When the calculation completes, execution will resume in the UI thread with the statement that comes after the `await ...` call.

`async/await` can be used to make *asynchronous* IO calls to databases, servers and files. In this case there is no background processing. Instead of blocking while waiting for the server or disk to respond, the UI thread is released and execution resumed when the asynchronous call completes :

```
public async void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArguments arg)
{
    var client=new HttpClient();
    ....
    var result=await client.GetStringAsync(someUrl);
    txtBox1.Text=result;
}
```

In many cases, you want to queue some data for eventual processing, eg writing to a log file from multiple threads or tasks. Or, you may have a thread that produces data that another thread/task needs to consume without blocking the original thread.

There are numerous techniques and classes that can be used in this case.

Perhaps the most straigh-forward is to use the ActionBlock class from the TPL Dataflow library. It allows other threads to post messages to it asynchronously, it buffers the data and processes the messages using one or more tasks. By default, only one task is used :

```
var logBlock= new ActionBlock<string>(msg=>File.AppendLine("log.txt",msg));
```

logBlock.Post("Hello!");

An ActionBlock that uses eg 10 concurrent tasks can be used for example to send multiple HTTP requests at the same time

```
HttpClient client=new HttpClient();

var options=new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions{MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10};
var downloadBlock= new ActionBlock<Tuple<string,string>>(async msg=>{
    var content=await client.GetStringAsync(msg.Item1);
    await File.AppendText(msg.Item2,content));
}

downloadBlock.Post(Tuple.Create(someUrl,someFile));
```

One can specify more options, eg BoundedCapacity places an upper limit on the number of messages that can be queued, preventing overflow if the producer/poster is too fast.

ActionBlock is part of the TPL Dataflow library. Another interesting block is TransformBlock which returns a result in an output buffer. Multiple blocks can be linked so that each block executes a processing step in a different thread.

Another common scenario is Producer/Consumer. In this case, one thread produces data, places it "somewhere" and another thread consumes and processes that data.

That somewhere can be [ConcurrentQueue< T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx), one of the concurrent collections of .NET. These classes are thread-safe, which means that multiple threads can read and write to them concurrently without risking corruption.

```
var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>(10);

var producer = Task.Run(async ()=>{
        for(i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            queue.Enqueue($"Message {i}");
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
    });

var consumer = Task.Run(()=> {
    while(true)
    {
        if (queue.TryDequeue(var out msg))
        {
            File.AppendLine("log.txt",msg);
        }
    }
});
```

You can avoid polling by using [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) whose `Take` method blocks if there are no messages. Internally, it uses a ConcurrentQueue, although that can be changed eg to a ConcurrentStack :

```
var queue = new BlockingCollection<string>(10);

var producer = Task.Run(async ()=>{
        for(i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            queue.Add($"Message {i}");
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
        queue.CompleteAdding();
    });

var consumer = Task.Run(()=> {
    while(!queue.IsCompleted)
    {
        var msg=queue.Take();
        File.AppendLine("log.txt",msg);
    }
});
```

Finally, the [BufferBlock< T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-messages-to-and-read-messages-from-a-dataflow-block) class from TPL Dataflow provides `ReceiveAsync` so there's no need to block waiting for a message :

```
var queue = new BufferBlock<string>();

var producer = Task.Run(async ()=>{
        for(i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            queue.Post($"Message {i}");
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
        queue.Complete();
    });

var consumer = Task.Run(async ()=> {
    while(!queue.Completion.IsCompleted)
    {
        var msg=await queue.ReceiveAsync();
        File.AppendLine("log.txt",msg);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining in details. I think ConcurrentQueue could resolve my problem that I used to think multithreading would always somehow need a lock, but you made it much clearer. :) and sorry I was stuck in my own thought yesterday and didn't update my edits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SyncronizationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) to do that. [Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31971/Understanding-SynchronizationContext-Part-I) is an example on how to use it. Hope it helps.

Comment: That's not the job of SynchronizationContext. You'll notice that the article you point to is **ancient**. The TPL came out a year after that article. Nowadays we have Tasks, concurrent Collections, Dataflow, `async/await`

Answer (score 0):

I think the arguments of not using a queue are not solid. You have to be sure to minimize the code/time of locking.

I wrote a nice class for it which also support batching. You can check it and might give inspiration:

**WorkerThread:**

```
// A worker thread that will run an action and batchup items.
public class WorkerThread<T> : IDisposable
{
    private Thread _thread;
    private List<T> _workItems = new List<T>();

    private ManualResetEvent _terminating = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private AutoResetEvent _hasItems = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    private DateTime _lastExceedMessageDisplayed = DateTime.MinValue;

    public WorkerThread(Action<T[]> action, int maxBatchSize = 16, int queueLengthWarning = 1000, double queueLengthExceedMessageTimeoutSeconds = 2, ThreadPriority threadPriority = ThreadPriority.Normal)
    {
        if (action == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

        if (maxBatchSize < 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("maxBatchSize", "must be higher than 0");

        if (queueLengthWarning < 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("queueLengthWarning", "must be higher than 0");

        _thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                var handles = new EventWaitHandle[] { _terminating, _hasItems };

                while (true)
                {
                    // wait if one of the handles is set.
                    int index = EventWaitHandle.WaitAny(handles);

                    // create copy of queue
                    T[] items;

                    int totalQueueLength;
                    lock (_workItems)
                    {
                        totalQueueLength = _workItems.Count;
                        items = _workItems.Take(maxBatchSize).ToArray();
                        _workItems.RemoveRange(0, items.Length);

                        if (totalQueueLength > items.Length)
                            _hasItems.Set();
                    }

                    if (items.Length > 0)
                    {
                        if ((totalQueueLength > queueLengthWarning)
                            && (_lastExceedMessageDisplayed.AddSeconds(queueLengthExceedMessageTimeoutSeconds) < DateTime.UtcNow))
                        {
                            var msg = "WorkerThread: Queue length exceed limit " + queueLengthWarning + " with " + totalQueueLength;
                            Trace.TraceWarning(msg);
                            _lastExceedMessageDisplayed = DateTime.UtcNow;
                        }

                    }

                    // check if the terminating is set and not actions are queued..
                    if (_terminating.WaitOne(0) && (items.Length == 0))
                        break;

                    action(items);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                var msg = exception.ToString();
                Trace.TraceError(msg);
            }

        });
        _thread.IsBackground = true;
        _thread.Priority = threadPriority;
        _thread.Start();
    }

    public bool Add(T item)
    {
        // do not add new items when terminating
        if (_terminating.WaitOne(0))
            return false;

        lock (_workItems)
        {
            _workItems.Add(item);
            _hasItems.Set();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool AddRange(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        // do not add new items when terminating
        if (_terminating.WaitOne(0))
            return false;

        lock (_workItems)
        {
            _workItems.AddRange(items);
            _hasItems.Set();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _terminating.Set();
        _thread.Join();
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
// create the workerthread
_workerThread = new WorkerThread<Message>(
    (messages) =>
    {
        using (var writer = File.AppendText("myFile.log"))
            foreach (var message in messages)
                writer.WriteLine(message);
    });


_workerThread.Add("Hi there");
_workerThread.Add("Second line");
```

Comment: ActionBlock<T> already provides such functionality using tasks. So does using Tasks with a single-threaded TaskScheduler

Comment: I'm not using tasks in my server software. Tasks are usefull in UI software. I avoid them in server software.

Comment: Why not? They are built-in, they run well, they do use thread-pools which your code doesn't, so they don't have to pay the cost of creating a thread. They support graceful cancellation, combining, progress reporting which can't be done with raw threads. As far as *this* problem is concerned, an ActionBlock would be no different than this code - a single task would process all input.

Comment: Threadpools are only usefull when indefinite number of threads/task are needed. In my case i'm programming robotic machines. I've used the threadpool but clogged execution of jobs (algorithms for controlling robot jobs). A fixed thread per robot dealt with it. Tasks might be great, but not for deterministic jobs. Also the threadpool doesn't give insight info about execution delays. The batching is usefull when locking is needed. And my solution is based on my work and might be not the best option for the OP. It might give some inspiration.

Comment: On the contrary, by having *minimum* and *maximum* thread limits, ThreadPools were generated to handle fixed numbers of threads just fine. Hard to argue that creating 100 threads one by one is better than having 100 threads ready for use. The default maximum is around 8000. All the concepts came out of the Robotics runtime, with Dataflow using almost the same abstractions. You are describing agents anyway, which have no problem working with tasks

Comment: What is the advantage of a threadpool with fixed threads controlled by a scheduler over a thread per robot with a loop of `ManualResetEvent.Wait(timeout)`. I did use the threadpool with a scheduler and it clogged. I also noticed some overhead by queuing UserWorkItems. I think the TPL/threadpool is great for UI/non-deterministic services. I even got rid of the async socket communications which performed at 75% of non-async sockets. It runs on 144 messages per second. Like i said, the OP is using another segment of the market and my solution might not be 100% applicable.